# the problem of torchto onnx, WARNING: The shape inference of custom::deform_conv2d type is missin

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, onnx, paddle-paddle

I want to transfer my torch file to onnx format, but some warning occur during the transferring:

> WARNING: The shape inference of custom::deform_conv2d type is missing,
> so it may result in wrong shape inference for the exported graph.
> Please consider adding it in symbolic function.

my code:

```
import torch
import torchvision

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 18, 3)
self.conv2 = torchvision.ops.DeformConv2d(3, 3, 3)

    def forward(self, x): 
        return self.conv2(x, self.conv1(x)) 

from torch.onnx import register_custom_op_symbolic
from torch.onnx.symbolic_helper import parse_args

@parse_args("v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "none")
def symbolic(g,  
input,
weight,
offset,
mask,
bias,
stride_h, stride_w,
pad_h, pad_w,
dil_h, dil_w,
n_weight_grps,
n_offset_grps,
use_mask):
return g.op("custom::deform_conv2d", input, offset)

register_custom_op_symbolic("torchvision::deform_conv2d", symbolic, 9)

model = Model()
input = torch.rand(1, 3, 10, 10)
torch.onnx.export(model, input, 'dcn.onnx')
```

I have try to setType, but not work. I hope my transferred process of '.onnx' file without warning.(Casue I will transfer 'onnx' to 'paddle' format, wrong shape inference bring a lot mistakes)